# How could I join these queries together?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 queries. One includes a subquery and the other is a pretty basic query. I can't figure out how to combine them to return a table with name, workdate, minutes_inactive, and hoursworked.

I have the code below for what I have tried. The simple query is lines 1,2, and the last 5 lines. I also added a join clause (join punchclock p on p.servrepID = l.repid) to it.

Both these queries ran on their own so this is solely just the problem of combining them.

```
select 
    sr.sr_name as liaison, cast(date_created as date) workdate, 
    (count(date_created) * 4) as minutes_inactive,
    (select 
         sr_name, cast(punchintime as date) as workdate,
         round(sum(cast(datediff(minute,punchintime, punchouttime) as real) / 60), 2) as hoursworked,
         count(*) as punches
     from
         (select 
              sr_name, punchintime = punchdatetime,
              punchouttime = isnull((select top 1 pc2.punchdatetime 
                                     from punchclock pc2 
                                     where pc2.punchdatetime > pc.punchdatetime 
                                       and pc.servrepid = pc2.servrepid 
                                       and pc2.inout = 0 
                                     order by pc2.punchdatetime), getdate())
          from 
              punchclock pc
          join 
              servicereps sr on pc.servrepid = sr.servrepid
          where 
              punchyear >= 2017 and pc.inout = 1
          group by 
              sr_name, cast(punchintime as date)))
from 
    tbl_liga_popup_log l
join 
    servicereps sr on sr.servrepID = l.repid
join 
    punchclock p on p.servrepID = l.repid collate latin1_general_bin
group by 
    cast(l.date_created as date), sr.sr_name
```

I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 19
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'

I keep getting this error but there are more errors if I adjust that part.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that we'll fix everything here, but there are a few issues with your query.

1. You have to alias your sub-query (technically a derived table, but whatever)
2. You have two froms in your outer query.
3. You have to join to the derived table.

Here's an crude example:

```
select
<some stuff>
from
(select col1 from table1) t1 
inner join t2
on t1.col1 = t2.col2
```

Answer (score 0):

The large error here is that you are placing queries in the `select` section (before the `from`). You can only do this if the query returns a single value. Else, you have to put your query in a parenthesis (you have done this) in the `from` section, give it an alias, and join it accordingly.

You also seem to be using `group by`s that are not needed anywhere. I can't see aggregation functions like `sum()`.

My best bet is that you are looking for the following query:

```
select 
    sr_name as liaison
    ,cast(date_created as date) workdate
    ,count(distinct date_created) * 4 as minutes_inactive
    ,cast(punchintime as date) as workdate
    ,round(sum(cast(datediff(minute,punchintime,isnull(pc2_query.punchouttime,getdate())) as real) / 60), 2) as hoursworked
    ,count(*) as punches
from 
    punchclock pc
    inner join servicereps sr on pc.servrepid = sr.servrepid
    cross apply
    (
        select top 1 pc2.punchdatetime as punchouttime
        from punchclock pc2 
        where pc2.punchdatetime > pc.punchdatetime 
            and pc.servrepid = pc2.servrepid 
            and pc2.inout = 0 
            order by pc2.punchdatetime
    )q1
    inner join tbl_liga_popup_log l on sr.servrepID = l.repid
where punchyear >= 2017 and pc.inout = 1
```